# How to configure Google SSO to only accept email addresses with specific domain?

Tags: amazon-web-services, authentication, single-sign-on, amazon-cognito, federated-identity

I am using AWS Cognito and Amplify. Through Cognito, I am using Google as a federated identity provider. How can I configure it so that only users with email addresses with a specific domain can sign-in through Google? And is it possible to specify two different domains?

Answer (score 0):

You can customize the Cognito authentication workflow by adding Lambda Triggers. In this case I'd suggest looking at a [Pre-Authentication Trigger](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/user-pool-lambda-pre-authentication.html). Your Lambda function could check the email domain and return an error if it doesn't match those in your list of accepted domains.